# Workflow to enable particular users to modify a field in HP QC

Tags: hp-quality-center

Could you please let me know as how to create a workflow to enable particular users to modify a specific field in HP QC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have seperatet your users into groups you can use a the following codesnippet as an example:

```
If user.IsInGroup("GROUPNAME") Then
Bug_Fields("BG_USER_31").IsReadOnly = True
Bug_Fields("BG_USER_32").IsRequired = True
Bug_Fields("BG_USER_33").IsVisible = True

End If
```

if you want to set the rights for a specific user use:

```
If User.UserName = "USERNAME" Then
Bug_Fields("BG_USER_31").IsReadOnly = True
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to write a workflow for that, that can be done by adding that person to some customized group and then modifying the permissions of that group and selecting which fields can be edited and which cannot.